# How to use a ternary operator in a template literal with multiple variables

Tags: javascript, string

I have a JSON file that I'd like to get values from and display. I tried to use a ternary operator but I couldn't seem to get the output I wanted since I have multiple variables. Here's what I tried:

```
//If there's a word, display its character / reading. Otherwise, just display the reading
return `${json.data[0].word} ? ${json.data[0].word (${json.data[0].reading}) : ${json.data[0].reading}`
```

This just outputs the actual string but with undefined if json.data[0].word is undefined. I'd like to only display the reading in this case.

Comment: Could you add an example of the json data?

Comment: Template literals are Strings. This looks like a pointless use of them. Just use the Object code. `json.data[0].word ? json.data[0].word(json.data[0].reading) : json.data[0].reading;`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Placeholders don't work recursively in String templates.
Write a clearer code.

If you insist in using a compact ternary code:

```
json.data[0].word
  ? `${json.data[0].word} (${json.data[0].reading})`
  : `${json.data[0].reading}`
```

Your external placeholder is unnecessary.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. Should I have written it like how Ryan Fletcher suggested?

Comment: Your choice, that depends on your personal coding style and of your project code.

Answer (score 0):

There is a much easier way to go about this. First I would create a variable that contained the resulting evaluation, and simply returned a literal of that result.

Then I would split up the nested ternaries into a set of nested if statements that are much easier to understand and modify in the future. Take a look at the code block below, you should be able to structure your code very easily and cleanly. Nested ternaries I believe to be very bad practice, and should be avoided at all times.

```
let $result;

if (true) {

   if (true) {
      $result = 'output 2';
   } else {
      $result = 'output 3';
}
   $result = 'output 1';
}

return `${result}`;
```

Comment: nested if is evil. don't do so.